# Get return of function of class in aurelia view

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, viewmodel, aurelia

[EDIT 1: precising my http request]

My goal is to make an asynchronous call to convert a number into a string and display it to the user in the browser. I'm using aurelia-http-client to make the call.
First, I tried with a value converter, then I read here that you couldn't do anything asynchronous with these converters. Now I'm trying with class and functions but it doesn't seem to work either.
Here is what I put in my *.ts file (model, calling a webservice giving the real title of a track using its position and release reference):

```
interface ITrack {
    position: number;
    reference: number;
    realPosition: number
}

class Track implements ITrack {
  position: number;
  reference: number;
  realPosition: number;

  public getTitle() {
      console.log('Getting title');  
        return `This track is the ${this.realPosition} of ${this.reference}.`;

    let client = new HttpClient();
    var json_tmp;
    var realTitle = 'tmp';

    client.get('http://localhost:8800/webservice/' + this.reference)
      .then(data => {
        console.log('### START DATA');
        console.log(data.response);
        console.log('### END DATA');
        var json_tmp = JSON.parse(data.response);
        realTitle = json_tmp.tracklist[this.realPosition].title;
        console.log('### RESPONSE: ' + realTitle);
      })
      .then(function(res) {
        console.log('### we are sending: ' + realTitle);
        return(reponse);
      });

    }
}
```

And here is what I put in the view:

```
<span class="position">${track.realPosition}</span>/<span class="reference">${track.reference}</span>
- <span class="content">${track.getTitle()}</span></p>
```

The "realPosition" and "reference" display correctly, by "getTitle()" isn't triggered, I have nothing in the console...

Am I handling this wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a lucky guess, not an answer: try changing `public getTitle() {` to `public get Title() {` and use it in view same as other properties: `${track.Title}`

Comment: Pretty sure you can't use functions with string interpolation. I don't see where the HTTP request fits in with your code?

Comment: Sorry, I cut too many lines. I don't want to bother you with unnecessary lines that don't have anything to do with the present problem.

Comment: @jevgenig: unfortunately, your guess didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Write an activate method inside your viewmodel, which expects a promise, then call the getTitle method inside the activate(). Then the page will load only after loading the title.

```
class Track implements ITrack {
    position: number;
    reference: number;
    realPosition: number;

    public activate(): Promise < void > {
        return getTitle();
    }

    public getTitle(): Promise < void > {
        console.log('Getting title');
        //here you can call the aurelia http method like this
        return httpClient.getTitle().then((data) {
            this.position = data.position;
            this.reference = data.reference;

        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Mmm activate can be a good solution. I tried to implement your code with my http request but I don't think I get it. I edited my initial post to explain more about the request I make: I take 2 numbers and get a string after calling a webservice with these numbers as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's the use of this return statement:

```
return `This track is the ${this.realPosition} of ${this.reference}.`;
```

everything in the function after that 'return' won't be executed, including:

```
let client = new HttpClient();
```

As already pointed out by others, the best solution is to call the async http call in the activate method, exactly as suggested in the Aurelia Skeleton example at https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/blob/master/skeleton-typescript/src/users.ts

After that you only need to read the property from the template without invoking any method